# Compiling libraries with CMake under Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, cmake, tinyxml

I have been trying to compile TinyXML using CMake as a sort of mini project, trying to learn CMake. As an addition I am trying to make it compile into a dynamic library and install itself so it works.

So far I have managed to get it to compile and install BUT it compiles into a .dll and a .dll.a and the only way to get it to work is to have it install into both /bin and /lib, which makes it install both files in both folders. This setup works but I'm guessing the .dll should be in /bin and the .dll.a should be in /lib. Is this some sort of Cygwin-specific problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Post your `CMakeLists.txt`, so people have a chance of guessing the problem.

Comment: I'd be interested in someone answering on how to make this a static library as well. *.lib I think?

Answer (score 3):

The .dll is the runtime library file, which must be present on the target system on run time (and be in $PATH there). The .dll.a file is the import library for the .dll, which must be present on the compiling machine at link time. You need to distribute the .dll file to the places where the program should run, and both .dll and .dll.a to places where the library is used to link other programs. you don't need the .dll.a file on the machines running the program only.

When you don't want to create a shared library, you can tell this to cmake with the [static keyword](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_library) in the add_library command:

```
add_library(mylib STATIC foo.c bar.cpp)
```

This way there will no shared library created, but the code from the library will be added by the linker into the final executable file.

Comment: Do you really need the DLL in lib/? Conventions on DLL-platforms are that executables (which the DLL is considered to be) should go in PATH (= /bin). That leaves the dll.a which should be in /lib. I have yet to see that Cmake understands this out of the box. Anyone?

Comment: @ThomasNilsson I meant that the .dll.a file is needed on machines where the library is linked into other programs. It os not needed to have them installed in bin/, it must only taken care that the import lib is in the linker search path at link time.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to specify a destination for each type of file.

The .dll is considered a RUNTIME library and the .a is an ARCHIVE. Just in case, for other platforms, you probably want the LIBRARY entry (for .so files).

```
install( TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```