# What library types are expected in Cygwin gcc?

Tags: gcc, cmake, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin 2.9.0-2, which included cmake 3.6.2.  I'm trying to get a cmake file developed on CentOS using cmake 2.8 to run.  It's a large cmake file, importing a variety of libraries, and includes compiling all of the unit tests to run again gtest.

I've a total lack of understanding of whether cygwin gcc wants Windows or Linux libraries for linking input, and what it produces.  I haven't been able to google the answer to this question: does Cygwin expect .a/.so or .lib/.dll files for compiled in libraries, does it create the same, or does it not care at all.  After all, it is compiling an executable that is to be run on Windows, so I would expect it to only produce `.lib/.dll`, and to expect them as well.

What has me confused is that I've cloned the gtest repo and it built and installed to `/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a`, and I've linked in my vendor's `*.lib` libraries, but the linker can't find the gtest libraries.  Do I need to modify the gtest cmake to produce `.lib` instead of `.a`?

There are so many things that I could try to finish porting this cmake file that I'm not sure where to start, and this lack of understanding is killing me.  I feel that if I understood this, then I could make a better decision about moving forward.

The Cygwin gcc man page implies that -lLibName looks for the file libLibName.a to link in.  Same as Linux.  Great.  So why does VendorLib.lib link in?  (All indications are that it is linking in because I had link errors go away once I got cmake to correctly search and locate the library.)

If the best explanation is a link to the proper documentation, I'll accept that as the answer.  If that's it, I just can't locate the documentation.  TIA SO users!

**Update:**

Configuring cmake to use 64-bit linux libraries, I get the following message outputs from cmake:

```
-- Found Ballard library /usr/local/lib64/ballard/libbtiCard.so
-- Found Ballard library /usr/local/lib64/ballard/libbti1553.so
```

And the following from make:

```
/usr/local/lib64/ballard/libbtiCard.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't get this error message when compiling with the Windows `.lib` static libaries.  Renaming from `.so` to `.dll.a` didn't change anything.

I don't need a special build for Cygwin, do I?  Is this just a problem with the vendor's library, and not with Cygwin, and I need to get with them to address the issue?

**Final Update**

I copied my vendor's WIN64/VENDOR.LIB to /usr/local/lib64/vendor/libVendor.a.

I copied my vendor's Linux/API64/*.h to /usr/local/include/vendor/*.h

I also added the following line to my cmake file so it would search the lib64/ path:

```
set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS TRUE )
```

and then moved compiled google test/mock libraries from /usr/local/lib to /usr/local/lib64.  There were other things unrelated to this question I had to change, but these are all covered in other SO questions.  What an awesome community!

Comment: Looks like there's some interesting stuff running under the hood. I think they kept the .a and .so extensions for makefile compatibility. But in the end it's all x86 assembler and Window's native exe format.

Comment: So do I need to rename the Windows libraries so that they have a .a extension?

Comment: I reckon it's not done with just renaming. Both .a and .dll.a have that `!<arch>` preamble and a .dll.a doesn't look like there's any dll embedded. (eg libssp.dll.a)

Comment: The libssp.dll.a has tons of references to cygssp-0.dll. I guess it's just a wrapper to provide access to it.

Comment: [Cygwin documentation](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) states that *.dll.a files are import libraries, and that *.dll files are DLLs.  So they do, indeed, serve different purposes.

Comment: I bet there's some sort of import tool that creates a .dll.a from a .dll. And .so files are ELF format, I doubt this will run on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On cygwin the import libraries are named

libNAME.a for static version
libNAME.dll.a for shared version

The packages containing header and import libraries are named
{lib}NAME-devel.

As example:

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep glpk
glpk                                    4.63-1
libglpk-devel                           4.63-1
libglpk40                               4.63-1

 $ cygcheck -l libglpk-devel |grep usr/lib
/usr/lib/libglpk.dll.a

$ cygcheck -l libglpk40
/usr/bin/cygglpk-40.dll
```

So `libglpk-devel` package contains the shared import library `libglpk.dll.a`.
The corresponding shared lib used by the other programs is `cygglpk-40.dll`

Import library called `NAME.lib` are windows one and you should not mix or use them when building a cygwin program.

Comment: I found this SO question that sheds more light: [Compiling Libraries with cmake under Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763212/compiling-libraries-with-cmake-under-cygwin?rq=1).  I'm starting to think that what I had before was correct, just incorrectly named files, and that my gtest compilation is the real cause for my linking errors.

Comment: This answer pretty much answers my question, though my problem isn't entirely solved.  But it did allow me to do some more experimentation, realize the Windows libraries are the ones I need, and get to the point where I can see that gtest isn't found because my linker search path is incomplete.  Once I've got it all worked out I'll post my end result as a question edit.  Thanks @matzeri!